# Ember component custom action

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a custom component that I'd like to attach a user interaction action to:

```
pro-form-price-field{action 'saveCatalogTicket' ticket on='focus-out'} currency="usd" value=ticket.base_price class='inline-field inline-field-medium'
```

This fails to compile. Any ideas to how I can attach an onFocusOut to a custom component?

Comment: What part of this is your component? The `pro-form-price-field` part? You're missing curly braces or angle brackets around it and a second pair of curly braces around the action, but you shouldn't an action like that on a component.

Comment: For inputs, this works.
                        focus-out="saveCatalogTicket"}}

Answer (score 1):

Just place [focusOut](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_event-names) function in `pro-form-price-field.js` file.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { on } from Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  focusIn(){
  },
  // or as Thernys pointed out use on event.
  saveCatalogTicket: on('focusOut', function(){
  })
});
```

Comment: Alternate syntax if you'd like to name your functions descriptively: `saveCatalogTicket: function() {}.on('focusOut')`